# Troponym vs hyponym vs hypernym

Tags: semantics, lexical-semantics, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation

I came across following table in Jurafsky's [book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/):

[image]

Note that it calls noun subordinate as "hyponym" and verb subordinate as "troponym". But it names both noun superordinate and verb superordinate as "hypernym"? Why different terms are used for noun subordinate and verb subordinate but the same term is used for superordinate? Is there any linguistic reason? Or is there indeed another term for verb superordinate?

Comment: hyper-onym looks better than the barbaristic hyper-nym.

Comment: On troponymy https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0073-3_2